# Indefinite Integral Confusion

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Solve the indefinite integral $$\int\frac{x^3−11x^2+x+2}{x^4−2x^3}\text{d}x.$$
My answer was $\frac{1}{2 x^2}+\frac{1}{x}-4\log(2-x)+5\log(x)+ C$ and I put that into my webwork and it was wrong. Then I tried again and got $5\log(x) + 4\log(x - 2)+ \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{2(x^2)}$ and that was still wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

We can write
\begin{align}
\frac{x^3-11x^2+x+2}{x^4-2x^3} & = \frac{A_1}{x}+\frac{A_2}{x^2}+\frac{A_3}{x^3}+\frac{B}{x-2}
\end{align}
for $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$ and $B$ real numbers such that
\begin{align}
x^3-11x^2+x+2 & =\left[\frac{A_1}{x}+\frac{A_2}{x^2}+\frac{A_3}{x^3}+\frac{B}{x-2}\right]x^3(x-2) \\
& = A_1x^2(x-2)+A_2x(x-2)+A_3(x-2)+Bx^3 \\
& = (A_1 + B)x^3+(-2A_1+A_2)x^2+(-2A_2+A_3)x-2A_3
\end{align}
So
\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcr}
  A_1 &   &      &   &      & + & B & = &   1 \\
-2A_1 & + &  A_2 &   &      &   &   & = & -11 \\
      & - & 2A_2 & + &  A_3 &   &   & = &   1 \\
      &   &      & - & 2A_3 &   &   & = &   2
\end{array}
Solving this system of equations we obtain $A_1=5$, $A_2=-1$ $A_3=-1$ and $B=-4$.
Then 
\begin{align}
\int{\frac{x^3-11x^2+x+2}{x^4-2x^3}dx} & = \int{\frac{5}{x}dx}-\int{\frac{1}{x^2}dx}-\int{\frac{1}{x^3}dx}-\int{\frac{4}{x-2}dx} \\
& =5\log|x|+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2x^2}-4\log|x-2|+C
\end{align}
Where $C$ is an integration constant.

Answer (score 1):

If the integral is evaluated over the real numbers, then you will want to use absolute values for the logarithmic terms:  $$\frac{1}{2x^2} + \frac{1}{x} - 4 \log |2-x| + 5 \log |x| + C.$$  Also, if your web-based homework system is picky about distinguishing between $\log$ and $\ln$, you will want to use $\ln$.  Mathematicians typically write $\log$ to mean $\ln$, because the base-10 logarithm $\log_{10} x$ is uncommon in pure mathematics.  Some computer algebra systems agree with this convention, and by default, a logarithm is always a natural (base-$e$) logarithm unless otherwise specified.

Comment: So does it matter if you use the absolute value symbol? Because it seems both I have the same answer without the it? It's usually not that picky but it keeps telling me that I have the wrong denominator. I'm just not sure how else I would change it.